# How to call the URL with token using restClient in Shopware?

Tags: symfony4, shopware

I am trying to call an external url. My URL looks something like this.

```
curl -X GET "https://api.manu.th/v1/list" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Token: token_number"
```

Now I am not able to implement it using Shopware 6. So far I have tried following lines of code.

```
$this->restClient = new Client();
$request = new Request(
            'GET',
            "https://api.manu.th/v1/list",
            [
                'Token' => 'token_number'
            ],
            ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
        );

        $response = $this->restClient->send($request);

        $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

This is returning me `is not callable: Invalid resource type: array", "meta": {`

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: What is the full class name of `Client` and the exact shopware version?